# New rsyslogd for Fedora?

Tags: fedora, kernel, logs, journalctl, rsyslogd

I have always used `rsyslog` for my Fedora installations (KDE only), to see informational messages in my (rooted) console, specially kernel messages. Yet, in the last Fedora versions it seems that this requires some setup. OTOH, Fedora already has other more modern tools to do this (I think).

How can I send selected kernel and auth log messages to the console automatically, like `rsyslog` did, using other modern alternatives?

**EDIT:**

I had set `ForwardToConsole=yes` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and I do see logs in the console, but way too many. How can I filter them, besides the too crude `MaxLevelConsole`?

My `/etc/rsyslog.conf` looks like this:

```
:msg, contains, "pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user root"   ~
:msg, contains, "pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root"   ~
:msg, contains, "pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root"   ~
:msg, contains, "pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root"   ~
:msg, contains, "pam_systemd(su-l:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session"   ~
:msg, contains, "pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session"   ~
module(load="imuxsock"    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
       SysSock.Use="off") # Turn off message reception via local log socket; 
module(load="imjournal"         # provides access to the systemd journal
       StateFile="imjournal.state") # File to store the position in the journal
global(workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog")
module(load="builtin:omfile" Template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
kern.info                           /dev/console
authpriv.*;authpriv.!=notice        /dev/console
```